# Best way to represent a date in a class (day month year vs. timestamp)

Tags: c++, class, date, datetime, time

Say we have a class that stores some date such as February 27, 2014. Consider these two possible implementations of that class:

1. Storing the day, month, and year
2. Storing the number of days since a reference date, e.g. January 1, 1900

Now I am told that the second way is a "better" or more preferred way, but I am unsure of why. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: I wouldn't say that at all. It depends on what else the class is expected to do. One way or the other might make certain calculations or certain ways of using dates quite a bit simpler. As it stands now I think your question is unanswerable (at least objectively) without more information about the requirements.

Comment: One of the advantages is that it makes date arithmetic easier. E.g. you can just add 20 dates without having to check if you change months, and in case you were in February, if the current year was a leap year, etc. You don't have to check that the day of the month is valid when you set it, so that becomes less of a headache as well. On the other hand, it makes formatting dates for display a bit harder. It depends what you will be doing most.

Comment: I hope it's ok that I edited the title. When I first read it, I thought you want to implement something which lets you choose between two classes using some compile time switch or a similar mechanic, thus I found it misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantages of storing the day, month and year separately:

- no overhead when retrieving / setting the individual components of the date
- no need to compute the actual date

Advantages of storing the number of days since January 1, 1900:

- smaller size (can count when having arrays of date, or when used as a field in another structure)
- easier and faster to perform operations between two dates (difference, comparison) or between a date and a time period (e.g. adding 3 days to the date or getting the tommorow value)

Answer (score 2):

There's no right or wrong way. A lot will depend on how much space you've got to encode the date and what you intend to do with it. The [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is the number of seconds since Thursday 1st January 1970 (in UTC) and I'm sure Thompson and Richie knew what they were doing when they picked it.

Windows uses the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since 1st January 1600 for its [FILETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) time and used a year/month/day/hour/minute/second/ms for its [SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) times, so even on one platform you can have multiple representations.

Comment: Indeed, the strategy varies. The old date-time classes in Java track *milliseconds*-since-Unix-epoch. The new java.time package in Java 8 tracks *nanoseconds*-since-Unix-epoch. If you do choose to track a count-from-epoch be sure to document well which resolution you chose.

Answer (score 1):

Both representations are used in practice, and both are reasonably common. Each has its unique advantages and disadvantages:

- The first representation lets you obtain the components of the date (i.e. day/month/year) without performing any computations
- Changing the first representation to a specific date does not require computations
- Unlike the first representation, the second one cannot be inconsistent (i.e. there is no way to represent Feb-**31**, 2014)
- Advancing the second representation by a specific time interval requires a very simple computation
- Storing the second representation in a data store that does not support dates requires less space

The advantages of each approach are hard to beat using the other approach. In fact, in some cases the same class library may feature two classes based on different representations of the date. For example, Java class library provides `java.util.Calendar` class, which implements an expanded version of the first approach, and `java.util.Date` class, which implements the second approach.

Comment: I just thought of another one... the second one is unambiguous with respect to daylight saving time (summer time).

Answer (score 0):

If you can consider other string formats, look at the standard one, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

- `2014-02-27T23:03:14` → local date-time, no time zone
  (not good if there is any chance of ambiguity in the context)
- `2014-02-27T23:03:14+3:00` → date-time three hours ahead of UTC.
- `2014-02-27T23:03:14-08:00` → eight hours behind UTC (west coast United States)
- `2014-02-27T23:03:14Z` → At UTC with no offset. Often called "Zulu" time, so the `Z` is short for Zulu and a substitute for `+00:00`.

The new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) extends this format by appending the name of the time zone in addition to the [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). A time zone is an offset *plus* rules and history about [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (DST) and other anomalies.

`2014-02-27T23:03:14-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]`

Notice that strings of this format sorts alphabetically into chronological order (if all in the same time zone).